# extJs tree: get a node from name

Tags: extjs

Is there a way to check/uncheck a node in extJS tree, if all we have is just the node name (with parent names till root). I am using ExtJS 3.3.0, couldnt find any method in the API documentation

Answer (score 2):

First: I guess the name does not match the Id of the node otherwise you are done with `treePanel.getNodeById()` [API link](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.tree.TreePanel-method-getNodeById)

You have the path of the node given the the `node.getPath()`

You just need to call

```
treePanel.expandPath(path, null, function(bSuccess, oLastNode){ oLastNode.select() });
treePanel.expandPath(path, null, function(bSuccess, oLastNode){ oLastNode.unselect() });
```

[API -Link](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.tree.TreePanel-method-expandPath)

with name you are meaning the text property of the node that does not match the node id or any other accessible attribute on the node:

- get your root node and the array of all child nodes from that
- take your path and get the first child after root
- iterate through the array till you found the matching on the node.text
- take the child array from this node
- take the next child from your path
- iterate through the array till you found the matching on the node.text
- and so on

finally you will reach your target node. Know you just need to call

Please note that I did not test the select / unselect behavior but it should check / uncheck the combo. for collapsing use either `toggle()` if you just want to change the state or `collapse()` / `expand()`